# Como adicionar um objeto dentro de um JSON

Tags: python, json, dataframe

Oi sou novo em python e estou tentendo ver um jeito de colocar um id dentro da estrutura do json

obs. fiz com replace mas acho que não ficou legal.

Estrutura do json:

```
[
  {
    "status_online": 0,
    "endereco_origem": {
      "lon": "-49.730152",
      "lat": "-23.437061"
    },
    "endereco_destino": {
      "lon": "-49.730152",
      "lat": "-23.437061"
    },
    "data_ini": "2023-01-09T00:00:39-03:00",
    "data_fim": "2023-01-09T08:09:06-03:00",
    "motorista": "",
    "cpf_motorista": "",
    "dispositivo_motorista": "",
    "distancia_percorrida": 0,
    "distancia": 0,
    "hodometro_inicial": "",
    "hodometro_final": ""
  }
  ]
```

Estou pegando essa string de uma chamada.

```
vDados = response.text
```

e eu queria saber se tem como eu adicionar uma novo objeto dentro do json:

```
"id_veiculo" : t
```

nessa estrutura acima, para identificar qual id se refere aqueles dados uma vez que a id vem na url e não dentro do json

```
cont = 0
d =[]
for id_veiculos in obj['veiculos']:
    t= id_veiculos['id_veiculo']
    url = f"https:.....{t}/{first_hour}/{last_hour}" 
    .
    .
    .    
    d.append(response.text) 
    vDados2 =  re.sub("},\"data_ini\"", "},\"id_veic\":" + str(t) + ",\"data_ini\"", d[cont])   
    
    df00 = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(vDados2))
    
    #concatatena todos os datafrmes
    df01 = pd.concat([df01, df00], ignore_index = 0) 
    cont =  cont + 1
```

Answer (score -1):

O método json.loads() permite converter o JSON num dicionário python que podemos modificar. Para converter de volta em JSON basta usar o método JSON.dumps().

```
data = json.loads(d)
data[0]['id_veiculo'] = 1
data_json = json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado!